# Reducing Server Calls or Improving Server Response Times?

Tags: programming-practices, server

In the company I am working for, we have been told to keep server requests to a minimum. There are probably reasons for this specific to the company, but it made me wonder.

Let's say I am building a basic web application with a standard Nginx/Apache server, would it be better in general to write server requests that try to get as much data as possible while on the server, or to just focus on reducing the times for long running server calls?

For example, let's say I am writing a page that needs data from three database tables. I could make three API calls to these tables, or make a new endpoint that grabs data from all the tables in one call to the server.

To me, it seems like a premature premature optimization to worry about things such as going to the server the fewest times, and because of async capabilities of most web/proxy servers, this may even be worse?

Just wanted to know if this is considered good practice to reduce server calls, since I had never heard of this before I worked at this company.

**Edit**: To be clear, I am not interested in *why* the company decided to do this. I am more interested in the practice. When building an application in a manner that can scale, is it necessary to keep server calls to a minimum?

Comment: You should really ask them, not us. Maybe your company is paying a ludicrous amount per request and can't get out of that contract? Maybe some manager read that for every 100 server calls a kitten dies somewhere? We don't know. There may be a good reason, they should be able to explain it. If not, they're most likely also not willing to discuss it, so getting good arguments here would be mostly useless...

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner My question doesn't really have to do with the company at all, I am just wondering if when talking about scaling an application if it is good in general to keep server requests low

Comment: and that's something that can't be answered in general. Of course you should not waste resources, but whether minimizing server requests avoids or generates waste is dependent on the specific situation.

Comment: Reducing the number of calls is generally the best way to improve performance and responsiveness since there is a certain unavoidable latency and overhead for each network request. Depending on circumstances, the network latency can easily dwarf the execution time on the server. Whether this is *premature* optimization depends on whether you are sure there even is a performance problem. And of course you should always identify the bottleneck before optimization.

Comment: I don't know why this is closed. the answer is unequivocal. Yes any upward calls should be reduced to minimum. when it comes to 1 vs 3 calls from the client, you have to consider caching and if some of those 3 calls can be used multiple times vs 1 call which is specific to the page

Comment: I have the impression some people hear “no premature optimisation” and misread it as “don’t write efficient code”.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Hans-Martin, it really depends on why you need to reduce the number of database calls.

If you have more resources on your web server than the data server does, it would make sense to cache as much data as possible on the web server and invalidate it only when it's changed.

You didn't specify what kind of API or technology the data server is using, or how many web servers are using it, but if the data calls are of the utmost importance then you might even consider having all the web servers talk to each other in order to invalidate, or possibly even update, the cache.

If you can have the web servers talk, then you will only be making data server calls to save and persist changes.